# Correct use of &quot

Tags: javascript, html

How would I print out quotation marks as in:

Steve said "hello world", not Steve said hello world?

```
var test = function(who,said) {
    alert(who + said);
}
test("Steve said ", "hello world");
```

I can see the answer involves '&quot' from another answer here but can't tell how to apply it here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: it's `&quot;` not `&quot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the option of escaping the double quotes:

```
test("Steve said ", "\"hello world\"");
```

or you can use single quotes:

```
test("Steve said ", '"hello world"');
```

Comment: Technically it would be `test("Steve said ", "\"hello world\"");`

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes to save you some backslashes.

```
test("Steve said ", '"hello world"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the double quotes in single quotes:

```
alert(who + '"' + said + '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your function slightly to

```
var test = function(who,said) {
    alert(who + '"' + said + '"');
}
test("Steve said ", "hello world");
```

if you are `alert()`-ing out the output. Or replace the quotation marks with `&quot;` if putting it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

To include quotation marks into strings that contain English-language texts, use English quotation marks. They cause no problems with string syntax in JavaScript, because they are distinct from the Ascii characters used as string delimiters. But you need to make sure that the character encoding of the file containing the code has been properly declared.

For common US English style, you would use

```
test("Steve said ", "“hello world”");
```

For common British English style, you would use

```
test("Steve said ", "‘hello world’");
```

If you cannot use the correct punctuation marks directly as characters, for some reason, you can use JavaScript escapes, e.g. for US style, you would use

```
test("Steve said ", "\u201chello world\u201d");
```